# There are some Catholics who disagree that Muslims and Catholics "worship the same God". What are their arguments that Allah is not God?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, islam

The Catholic Church teaches that *Muslims [...] adore the one and merciful God*.

> In the first place amongst these there are the Muslims, who,
>   professing to hold the faith of Abraham, along with us adore the one
>   and merciful God, who on the last day will judge mankind. - Cf.
>   [Dogmatic Constitution on the Church > Lumen gentium](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_en.html) and [**CCC
>   841**](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a9p3.htm#841).

There are some Catholics who disagree that Muslims and Catholics *"worship the same God"*. Thus to me disagreeing with Church teaching.

What are their arguments that Allah is not God?